# Does order of Tag matters in BER decoding using pyasn1

Tags: python-2.7, asn.1

**case :-** I need to decode a BER encoded data using pyasn1 , but the order of tag may vary some times. So while decoding the data it rises error. Is the order of Tag really matters even though it is optional Tag's?

**Note:-**     (case1)8 different Tag's in one CDR is in order: AF 30 81 82 83 84 85 86

```
     (case2)Another 8 Tags is in order : AF 30 81 83 84 85 86 82
```

But i need to decode both the order with single decoding structure  , is that possible ?

Here am giving my structure for reference ....

class ChangeOfCharCondition(univ.Sequence):

```
componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(

namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Requested', univ.OctetString().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1)))

namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Negotiated', univ.OctetString().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 2))),

namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Uplink', univ.Integer().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 3))),

namedtype.OptionalNamedType('Downlink', univ.Integer().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 4))),

namedtype.NamedType('changeCondition', univ.Integer().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 5))),

namedtype.NamedType('changeTime', univ.OctetString().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 6)))
    )
```

class TrafficVolumes(univ.SequenceOf):

```
tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,
                                             tag.tagFormatSimple, 15))

componentType = ChangeOfCharCondition()
```

class Cdr(univ.Set):

```
tagSet = baseTagSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,
                                             tag.tagFormatSimple, 20))
componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
namedtype.OptionalNamedType('TrafficVolumes', TrafficVolumes().subtype(
    implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 15))))
```

**Sample Data(case1)**- bytearray('\xaf200\x81\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x82\x0cx01\x12Q\x1fs\x96HHv\xfa\xff\xff\x83\x01\x00\x84\x01\x00\x85\x01\x02\x86\t\x12\x12\x10\x12\x00P+\x050') and it works fine

**Sample Data(case2)** - bytearray('\xaf200\x81\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00\x84\x01\x00\x85\x01\x02\x86\t\x12\x12\x10\x12\x00P+\x050\x82\x0cx01\x12Q\x1fs\x96HHv\xfa\xff\xff') in this case it raise error like ,
PyAsn1Error : TagSet(Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)) not in asn1Spec: None'

Comment: Are you sure that ChangeOfCharCondition should be a derivative of SEQUENCE, not a SET? Tags of the former must follow the order of specification, however SET tags may be re-ordered in encoding.